# Is the set $C_k$ closed or not?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $C_k=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|_0\leq k\}$, where $\|x\|_0$ is the number of nonzero entries of $x$. 
>   Is the set $C_k$ closed with respect to the topology induced from Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I do not see any question.

Comment: Is $C$ closed or not?

Answer (score 1):

The set $C_k=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|_0\leq k\}$ with $0\leq k\leq n$ 
is closed with respect to the Euclidean norm.

Let $(x_j)_j$ be a sequence in $C_k$ which converges with respect to the Euclidean norm to $y$ and assume that  $y\not \in C_k$. Thus  the number of nonzero entries of $y$ is greater than $k$. Consider the real sequences of the corresponding nonzero entries, then they are eventually non-zero. Therefore the number of nonzero entries of $x_j$ is eventually greater than $k$, i. e. $x_j\not\in C_k$. Contradiction.

Comment: Assume that for each component sequence $(x_j^k)_k$, we have $x_j^k \neq 0$ for almost $k$. But why you can claim $\|x_j\|_0 >k$? Which $j$?

Comment: The key-fact is that if a real sequence $(t_k)_k$ has a nonzero limit then $t_k$ is eventually different from zero.

Answer (score 1):

The function defined by $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $f(x)=$ nombre of entries of $x$ non zero is continuous for the Euclidean topology:

If $l\geq n, f^{-1}(l)$ is empty, otherwise $f^{-1}(l)$ is a finite union of affine subspaces.

This implies that $C$ is closed.

Comment: Please make it more clear? What is the topology on $\mathbb{N}$? When $l\geq n$, is $f^{-1}(l)=\emptyset$?

Comment: It is the discrete topology.